# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)

Tags: 7, hooks, theming

I've propagated the 3rd party PHP SDK for Facebook APIs using [Libraries](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) and I've also enabled [X Autoload](https://www.drupal.org/project/xautoload) but still I'm getting this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)

Below is my code:

```
/**
 * Libraries API 2
 */
$facebook_library = libraries_detect('facebook-php-sdk-v4');
// This statement is TRUE
if ($facebook_library['installed'] == 1) {
  require(libraries_get_path('facebook-php-sdk-v4') . '/autoload.php');
  use Facebook\FacebookSession;
  use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
}
```

Comment: This isn't Drupal-related - `use` statements need to go at the top of the file

Comment: @Clive, I just tried what you said and it worked, what if I want to add those `use` statements conditionally, for instance `if(TRUE) { use ..\..; }` any suggestions over this?

Comment: `use` statements can't be conditional, the parser needs them to be resolved before code execution starts

Comment: It would have been an off-topic if I was having an issue with the `use` but here, my issue is quite different. `use` are working fine without any conditional statement, so I need the Drupal way to add the use statements. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: OK, thanks for the help Clive, let me try some more work around.

Comment: Harking back to your earlier question, XAutoload probably can help with this - I think it can integrate well with libraries: https://www.drupal.org/node/2230319